# Remove the "StackTrace" alert of python program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I built a shell python code. It uses common sockets for connections.

If the connection fails, it prints a huge stacktrace.

I would like to take it out by adding something in the script.

Comment: `python ./my_prog_which_i_should_really_fix.py 2> /dev/null`? :)

Comment: Try searching your favorite search engine for "python exception handling".

Comment: [Catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), and do something useful with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace tells you where the exception occurs.

If you can do something about it and recover from the error, you could try catching the exception, and handling it yourself.

```
try:
    #line causing stacktrace
except ExceptionType, exception:
    #do something with exception
```